# Best algorithm for finding this data in an associative array?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, associative-array, depth-first-search

I'm working on a lab assignment right now to make a Hangman game, and there's one particular function I'm trying to work out. I have an associative array, which is just a binary tree where each node is a key/value pair, the key being a string, and the value being a vector of strings. The function of these isn't important for my question. What I need to know is this...

I need to return a pointer to the vector containing the greatest number of elements in the tree. I've tried to work out a way to do this with a depth-first search, but I can't quite work out what to compare and how to keep track of everything.

Can someone give me pseudo-code or an idea of how to do this?

EDIT: Here is my current algorithm.

```
GENERIC_VECTOR* find_greatest(Node* root, MYSTRING* pattern) {
    if(root != NULL) {
        GENERIC_VECTOR* left = find_greatest(root->left, pattern);
        GENERIC_VECTOR* right = find_greatest(root->right, pattern);
        int sizeL = generic_vector_size(*left);
        int sizeR = generic_vector_size(*right);
        int sizeT = generic_vector_size(root->data->value);
        if(sizeL > sizeR) {
            if(sizeL > sizeT) {
                mystring_destroy(pattern);
                *pattern = mystring_copy(root->left->data->key);
                return left;
            } else {
                mystring_destroy(pattern);
                *pattern = mystring_copy(root->data->key);
                return &(root->data->value);
            }
        } else {
            if(right != NULL) {
                if(sizeR > sizeT) {
                    mystring_destroy(pattern);
                    *pattern = mystring_copy(root->right->data->key);
                    return right;
                } else {
                    mystring_destroy(pattern);
                    *pattern = mystring_copy(root->data->key);
                    return &(root->data->value);
                }
            } else {
                mystring_destroy(pattern);
                *pattern = mystring_copy(root->data->key);
                return &(root->data->value);
            }
        }
    } else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: where is your effort???

Comment: The 8 hours I've spent on this weren't enough? I wouldn't be here if I hadn't already tried everything I could think of, so maybe you could give me some actual help?

Comment: @Darin... how can I help you until I check your effort. Please post your 8 hours effort.

Comment: Updated with my current algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Since your DS is a tree, you would have to use one of the tree traversal algos (ie, inorder, perorder or postorder):

PseudoCode:

```
global int maxval = -1;
global NODE *max = NULL; // this pointer will contain the result!

getMaxVal(NODE *n){
    if(n!==NULL){
        if( n->val[key].length > maxval ){
            maxval = n->val[key].length;
            max = n; 
        }
            getMaxVal(n->left);
            getMaxVal(n->right); 
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem with this is that I can't just get the maximum size... I'm not looking for the size. I'm trying to return a pointer to the vector (which is in the data of the node) with the greatest number of elements.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: NODE *max is the pointer you are looking for!

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: I meant, `*max` will have the node having the max element. Once you have this, just return a pointer to the vector array of this node.

Comment: Another problem is the global variables. I never use global variables if I can't help it. As far as I'm concerned, the only time global variables are called for are for constants and static values.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: In that case, use C++ classes and make the 2 global variables  member variables and getMaxVal a member function.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: Well, then I don't think there is a way around not using global variables. This is a limitation of C.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau: Also, how exactly are you implementing key-value pairs in C?

Comment: Instead of global variables one could pass pointers to some variables as additional arguments to `getMaxVal`.

Comment: @Henry: I believe this does not work with recursive functions. Do I declare this variable inside or outside the function? If it's inside, a new variable instance is created for each recursive function call, if it's outside it's a global variable ;)

Comment: @AmalAntony you declare it outside. This does not necessarily mean it is global, it can be a local variable of the calling function or it can be some dynamically allocated chunk of memory.